# Reading txt file from user input then returning result from that input

Tags: java

I  need to make this program for school.
It firstly prompts the user to enter in txt file, then it asks the user for a unique 3 letter code, and from the code the program will then read the txt file and return the information that is linked to that unique code.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class assignA
{
public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter the file name");
  String filename = keyboard.nextLine ();
  File f = new File (filename);
  Scanner fin = new Scanner (f);

  while(fin.hasNextLine());
  {
     String line = fin.nextLine ();


  }
```

}

Comment: Do you have an example for the file and the 3 letter code?

Comment: Even if we wanted to do your homework for you, *"the information that is linked to that unique code"* isn't a sufficient description of the desired output. Also I do not see the *"then it asks the user for a unique 3 letter code"*  part.

Comment: RXP#Roxburgh Park#20 September 2007
BEG#Belgrave#19 February 1962
FSS#Flinders Street#12 September 1854
TSN#Tecoma#1 February 1924
WGS#Watergardens#26 January 2002
CDA#Cardinia Road#22 April 2012
WFY#West Footscray#14 October 2013
HBE#Hurstbridge#25 June 1912
YMN#Yarraman#21 December 1976
DCK#Diamond Creek#25 June 1912
YVE#Yarraville#20 November 1871
BAY#Bayswater#4 December 1889
That is the format of the txt file, so pretty much the program is to ask the user enter the "stations code", if you enter BAY, baswater 4th december 1889 would appear as the output

Comment: im new to java, i just cant get my head around, how to code the program to read the text file find the user input unique  3 letter code, then output the information relating to it,                                                                                                             



> java Codes
Enter file name >> stationsMaster.txt
Enter station code >> RXP
Station name: "Roxburgh Park" has code "PRE" date built: 8 October 1889

that is the final output on how the program should work, im just really stuck on it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class assignA
{
public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter the file name");
  String filename = keyboard.nextLine ();
  File f = new File (filename);
  Scanner fin = new Scanner (f);

  String code = "RXP"; //You can replace it with a scanner input

  while(fin.hasNextLine());
  {
     String line = fin.nextLine();
     String[] detail = line.split("#");
     if (detail[0].equals(code)) {
         System.out.println(detail[1] + detail[2]);
         break;
     }


  }

}
```